# How I can instantiate various prefabs in a given time for each?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am developing a video game Guitar Hero type. I just finished everything. What I need is to configure the notes.

I have a script that instantiates me a prefab (a note) and generates time to time. But there is not only one note. There are 23 and I wonder if it is possible to instantiate each with different timers and within the same script.

For example, the first note should be generated to 1 second and second to 3 seconds.

This is the script that I have:

```
#pragma strict

var yellowNote: GameObject;
var time = 1;

function Start () {
    while (true) {
        yield WaitForSeconds (time);
        Instantiate (yellowNote, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an array of times you'd like between each instantiation. Then, iterate through the array with a for loop and do the `WaitForSeconds` inside this loop.

Comment: Mm... interesting. How I can do this with prefabs?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using my phone to respond. You could create a list of pairs <time, Game Object> then iterate through it to yield waitforseconds and instantiate accordingly.

Comment: See this link http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/405357/how-to-load-prefabs-into-array.html